# Changing the time in each column of a dataset in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to merge two datasets by time. Unfortunately one of the datasets is from a different time zone, so that there is a two hour difference in the time columns. Does anybody knows how to increase the time by two hours for each column in the dataset?

I am grateful for every suggestion :)

The time format is like this:

07:31:21

Comment: You did not provide sample data or code so I can't produce an example, but check non-equi joins of package `data.table`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution based largely on regex (I'm sure there are solutions based on packages that can 'read' time data too!). Suppose you have values such as these:

```
x <- c("07:31:21", "12:03:55", "21:07:01")
```

you can then do this to add two hours each:

```
library(stringr)
paste0(str_pad(as.numeric(sub("^(\\d{2}).*", "\\1", x)) + 2, width = 2, side = "left", pad = "0"), sub("\\d{2}(.*)","\\1", x))
[1] "09:31:21" "14:03:55" "23:07:01"
```

That's this bunch of operations:

- extract the hours with `sub` using backreference `\\1`
- convert them to numeric using `as.numeric`
- add `2`
- pad a `0` where necessary using `str_pad`
- extract anything that's **not** the hours
- paste the two separate substrings back together usng `paste0`!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the library `hms` and `lubridate` with the function `with_tz` which changes the time zone (the reference time zone being the one of your locale, me: `LC_TIME=French_Switzerland.1252`)

```
library(lubridate)
library(hms)
library(magrittr)

        
as_hms("07:31:21") %>%
  with_tz("America/New_York") %>%
  as_hms()

02:31:21
```

`as_hms` convert to a hms time, and you can use `with_tz`  to change the time zone (but lubridate will vonvert to a date, so 1970 and the time), and you convert it back to an `hms` format to have only the time.

If you only want to add a fixed amount, `hms` is in second, so you add 2*3600 second to add 2 hours:

```
as_hms(as_hms("07:31:21") + 2*3600)

09:31:21
```

Of course, it is vectorized:

```
x <- c("07:31:21", "12:03:55", "21:07:01")
x %>%
  as_hms() %>%
  with_tz("America/New_York") %>%
  as_hms()

02:31:21
07:03:55
16:07:01
```